# Pass full result set from execute sql task to an OLEDB command task

Tags: ssis, task

I have read some blogs that give an idea about passing the full result set into a variable and then sending the variable to a for each loop container. I am stuck there. Basically I have two tables: 1. student_Class_timetable 2. students_exams_timetable.
I have a sql query that finds out the clashes between these two tables for. eg. say a student has to attend a class today between 10 to 12 but he also has to write an exam at the same time.

So I am doing an execute sql task and saving the full result set in a variable called studentlist. I now need to save the list of all these students in  an audit log table before deleting them from student_Class_timetable.

[ssis_screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFwjP.png)
I don't know how to pass the Studentlist variable to a data flow task.

Could you please suggest a way to do that

Answer (score 0):

If I were doing that, I would consider storing the data in a Recordset Destination with an Object Type `VariableName` and using a Foreach ADO Enumerator on that variable. A good example can be seen [here](http://beyondrelational.com/modules/2/blogs/101/posts/13466/ssis-loop-through-rows-in-a-sql-table-with-multiple-columns.aspx).

Comment: I agree but recordset destination can be added when you are in data flow task. I am in control flow task and I want to get inside a data flow task using that variable.

Comment: Make a parameter with Object data type; add a data flow task to the Control Flow. Double click the data flow to look inside it. Within the Data Flow task, add an ADO Source Task with your execute SQL command and a RecordSet Destination Task, with the new parameter name in the properties; connect the two. On the Control Flow add a Foreach Loop and set the Collection Enumerator to Foreach ADO Enumerator, with the source variable as your new object parameter. Use the index to map the columns to variables; these can be used within the loop, by tasks including Data Flows.. is that what you mean?

Comment: No problem @manavya - please mark this as the answer if you consider the question answered